# I need to recreate my Rails 7 keys and I can't

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 7.0.4 app where I am using environmental credentials.

I screwed up and lost my keys. (developemt.key and production.key. Also master.key)

Ok I thought. I know what needs to be in the credentials so just go in, delete the files and run EDITOR='code --wait' rails credentials:edit --environment=production and it will create the new yml.enc file and the key.

It creates the new production.yml.enc file but NO production.key. It will run again WITHOUT the key in my config/credentials. It also just says it is saving the file, nothing about creating the key.

Same thing with my master.key.

Can anyone help me?  I tried echo $RAILS_MASTER_KEY and it's blank.

I deleted all file under config/credentials as well as credentials.yml.enc and all keys.

Then I ran EDITOR='code --wait' rails credentials:edit --environment=production

The yml.enc file is created but no key. Same if I run without --environment. No Master.key

Comment: What is output `ls -la config/credentials`?

Comment: `ls -la config/credentials`
`total 12`
`drwxr-xr-x 2 ray ray 4096 Jun 28 16:17 .`
`drwxr-xr-x 7 ray ray 4096 Jun 28 15:32 ..`

Nothing. Sorry, I can't figure out how to get line feeds.